# Grouping bottom three against one criteria

Tags: r, csv

I am looking at some sales data and trying to find the bottom 3 results for each day (the salesperson is irrelevant at this point).

Grouping by date sorts out the first part but then I try to find the top 3 using a negative top_n command and get the wrong results.

```
date    sales
14/11   39
14/11   3.2
14/11   13
14/11   8.3
14/11   5
14/11   5.6
14/11   79
14/11   35
14/11   24
14/11   8.1
14/11   21
14/11   40
14/11   50
14/11   82
15/11   8.3
15/11   7.2
15/11   63
15/11   31
15/11   35
15/11   2.1
15/11   31
15/11   11
15/11   3.8
15/11   29
15/11   ---
```

This I've saved as a csv which I read.csv as 'raw'. And then I write the code:

```
raw2 <- raw %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  top_n(n = -3, wt = sales)
```

Which returns:

```
date    sales
14/11   13
14/11   24
14/11   21
15/11   2.1
15/11   11
15/11   ---
```

I had tried it with a lot of other data but couldn't find other columns it would prioritise as a result but cleaned them out for this.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because of the presence of a non-numeric character ie `---` in the sales column. THis turns the class of the column into character. Hence the sorting will not occur based to the quantity but alphabetically, eg 2 comes after 1 thus 11 will come before 2.

**What to do** : 
 Replace all `---` with NA then make the column numeric and now use your code